# I can't add reference to namespace system.windows.controls in a library project

Tags: wpf, namespaces, assemblies

I'm trying to add a reference to the namespace System.Windows.Controls in a library project but i can't find it in the list.
Does anybody know what is going on? i'm using 4.0.
thanks.

Comment: In what list? There are many lists you can look through.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to learn to distinguish between assembly names and namespaces. They're not in a 1-1 correspondence.

If you're wanting to access e.g. [System.Windows.Controls.Button,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx) you need to reference  the `PresentationFramework` assembly, which does seem to contain most of the classes documented on MSDN as being in the [System.Windows.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590941.aspx) namespace.

Multiple assemblies can contribute classes/controls to a single namespace. And there's no requirement that all (or even the majority) of classes from an assembly all reside within a single namespace.

Comment: Actually my problem is a little bir bigger than that.
I have a project of a class library. In this project i have mutiple user controls. These controls uses a class "A" that inherits from "Contol".
I'm trying to make a mergd dictionary for all these user controls.
In the styles that exists in this dictionary is used the class "A".
and i'm having a run time problem loading this template because it can't create the type "A". i checked the problem and found that i have to add the reference System.Windows.Controls tot he project, but i didn't find it in the browser.

Comment: @Ziad - still, I think the crux of your question, and the answer you need, is that you need to add a reference to `PresentationFramework`. If that's not it, you need to edit your question and provide more information on what problem you're having.

Comment: @Ziad - there isn't an assembly called `System.Windows.Controls`. (Not in the framework anyway)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliver
I think this is a better explanation, but i'm trying on a desktop application and i got the same problem.
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/605907/silverlight-4-xamlparseexception-failed-to-create-a-system-type-from-the-text-local-customerentity

Comment: @Ziad - if you're working in Silverlight (your question just says WPF), then most of the controls are in the `System.Windows` assembly (note, still not `System.Windows.Controls`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS 2010:
Check you project settings: right click your Project, select "Properties", then select the "Application" tab. If the Dropdown for "Target framework" is ".Net Framework 4 **Client Profile**" you have to change it to ".net Framework 4".

Edit: I guess  the requried assembly is "**PresentationFramework.dll**" (see [msdn class info about Usercontrol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx)). My fault, Ijust thought it would the Client Profile, because I usualy make this error.

Comment: I'm very positive that `System.Windows.Controls` is available in the .NET client profile. Then again, worth a try.

Comment: My fault, edited my answer - I just thought it would be the Clientprofile and tested it locally. Since this is a common error i make, I thought this would be the problem. Since I do not develop Desktop applications, I am not an expert for the namespaces/assemblies. But MSDN helpds in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Windows ships with Silverlight toolkit. Hope that helps.